# Создание git сервера под Windows

Tags: windows, git

Доброго времени суток.

Проблема такая. Необходимо сделать аналог gitlab, но с хостом у меня на ПК. Чтобы несколько программистов могли работать с сервом с помощзью функционала гит команд.

Пока имеется такая проблема, что у нас нет домена и пока не предвидится.
Плюс маловато знаний и не совсем понятно куда идти.

Из попыток - разворачивали на ВМ линкуса gitlab, но он работал только на ip машины, максимум чего добились, что из моей винды я смог зайти по ip машины в web интерфейс.

Затем я развернул gogs, но опять же локально на localhost:3000. Гит работает, но второй человек не может подключиться(да, я понимаю, что локально) но у нас даже представления нет как подлкючиться вне локалки, ну или с ней, если нет аутов без домена.

Если обобщить все те абзацы, что находятся выше, то стоит задача, чтобы сервер лежал на машине 1(windows) и любой программист смог клонировать репозиторий по ssh или https на свою машину, когда сервер на машине 1 запущен.

По релевантности такой затеи - нам нужно держать собранный проект из кода + ассетов, но бесплатных хранилищ у гитлаба,хаба и т.д. не хватает, а денег на доп место еще нет

Собственно как и какими средствами можно сделать то, что я описал выше?

Заранее спасибо за ответы и всем хорошего вечера!

Answer (score 2):

Логично, что указывая localhost, они не смогут подключится к Вашей машине.

Давайте посмотрим, что можно сделать, не тратя лишних денег.

Если они с Вами в одной локальной сети - пусть указывают IP адрес Вашей машины и все будет работать. Если адрес указывать не хочется - нужно либо использовать функциональность роутера и прописать для нее удобное имя (к примеру, так умеют mikrotik (он конечно стоит немного денег) и вроде openwrt (а это прошивка для большинства роутеров и бесплатная)). Искать по слову dns server. В настройках gogs/gitea можно прописать в настройках "внешнее имя/base url" и всем будет показываться правильное имя.

Если хочется подключатся из вне, тогда нужно сделать следующее - на роутере пробросить порты (нужно как минимум для http и ssh, хотя можно и одним http обойтись), а также на любом бесплатном сервере приписать своему роутеру dns имя (гуглите на тему Free Dynamic DNS). Конечно, у роутера должен быть реальный внешний адрес (это может стоить немного денег). Без это сильно сложнее. Но возможно. Тот же hamachi может сильно помочь. Или IPv6.

Я думаю, что самый оптимальный вариант, использовать отдельно стоящую машину, что бы не быть зависимым на одну машину разработчика. Я бы использовал обычный raspberry pi или старый системник.

Comment: Спасибо, но есть еще парочка вопросов. Не совсем получается поставить сервер на внешний порт. Порт брал и с 2ip(у меня белый ip) и с ipconfig консоли. Если использовать radmin или хамачи, то нужно же указывать в app.ini в стркое domain и root-url ip , ведь так?

Comment: UPD. Получилось запустить в локальной сети через RAMIN , но теперь он не хочет давать клонировать даже мне через консоль, но сайт теперь виден

Comment: Попробуйте использовать http протокол, а не git для клонирования. Потом пробросите ssh порт и будет хорошо

Comment: Да, все получилось, ровно так и сделали, проблема была в https, нужно было использовать через http